# PHP wont urldecode() string from C++

Tags: php, c++, utf-8, urlencode

So I am sending a post message with one variable, it is a base64 encoded string that is UrlEncoded.

When I send the string over Firefox network debugger, it works fine.
I don't even need urldecode when using Firefox debugger, it's done automatically.

BUT when I send it from my C++ application it does not decode at all.

The string is a Unicode string, my C++ application is all Unicode.

I have `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` at the top of my php page to make sure.

My php application repeats the response back to the c++ application.

```
if($encData = input::get('x')){
    echo $encData;
}
```

I get my response but its not decoded, Even if i use `urldecode()` or `rawurldecode()`

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You should show your c++ application too ;)

Comment: How is it being sent? If it's in the URL parameters or POST data, PHP automatically decodes it.

Comment: I very well could, but i feel if i receive my response why can't i receive it decoded? Also yes php does it but it isnt ATM...

Comment: What is `input::get`? How does it relate to `$_POST` or `$_GET`?

Comment: public static function get($item){
  
  if(isset($_POST[$item])){
   return $_POST[$item];
  }elseif(isset($_GET[$item])){
   return $_GET[$item];
  }else{
   return '';
  }

 }

Comment: @swayz: No one is going to be able to help you without seeing C++ code that's sending the string, or, at least, the raw string as it's sent. You should use a program like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect what your C++ program is doing, and show us a minimal sample of C++ code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: the data is x=fAB%2BADia it is just a unicode string, the php script returns the value of x, which IS return succesfully. it just isnt decoded no matter what i do.

i use the HttpSendRequestW API to send the string.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/d2b3840b3383a45c4e68b5041b89efc8 obviously heres the problem

http://gyazo.com/e2ddc8f5fda0908851611a696b99df0f From my visual studio everything looks ok, and i checked the buffer its a valid unicode string.
http://gyazo.com/854b8feec1cb406b33303c3aaecdbdd0

so i dont understand?

Comment: It's the *wrong kind* of Unicode string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode is not one thing. Unicode refers to both the Unicode standard (the blocks of symbols that are associated with blocks of code points) and the *several encodings* that represent the code points for your text.

There are several types of strings. On Windows, for example, there are "ASCII" and "Wide" strings, hence the A and W suffixes on WinAPI functions. "ASCII" refers to the fact that it uses 8-bit `char`s in the string, and "Wide" refers (on Windows) to using **16-bit `short`s** for each character in the string. (Other platforms, like Linux, standardized on using 32-bit characters for wide strings.)

The [code sample you provided](http://gyazo.com/e2ddc8f5fda0908851611a696b99df0f) shows that you are using wide strings and sending them raw over the link. Windows' 16-bit wide strings normally use the UCS-2 Unicode encoding (which is very similar to, but not the same as, UTF-16), whereas PHP and the HTTP standard both expect 8-bit characters, and, by default, PHP expects UTF-8 strings. This is evident in the [data dump you provided](http://gyazo.com/854b8feec1cb406b33303c3aaecdbdd0), as it shows NUL bytes in between each 8-bit character. (This is what UCS-2 looks like when sending Latin-1 text.)

Since PHP expects UTF-8, and you are sending it UCS-2, PHP can't understand the text, and so its `urldecode` function can't do anything with it.

**You will need to convert your string to an 8-bit encoding before you send it.**